# SSIS job failure through SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

My SSIS package is running fine in Visual Studio locally. The package contains (at the end) a process task to execute an .exe file that generates a xml file.

Note: Earlier, The package was scheduled in SQL Server 2005 and it was running fine. Now, I have migrated this package to SQL server 2012 and creating agent job in 2012.

On **Monday 4 PM:**
I deployed the package to SSIS catalog and scheduled it to run every week day at 7 PM.

**Monday 7 PM:**
Job ran successfully.

**Tuesday 7 PM:**
Job Failed with error

> Executed as user: ProxyID. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package
>   Utility Version 11.0.5548.0 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved. Started: 11:05:02 AM Error:
>   2015-05-11 11:12:25.65 Code: 0xC0029151 Source: Execute XML Generator
>   Execute Process Task Description: In Executing
>   "\Servername\path\app.exe" "" at "", **The process exit code was
>   "-532459699" while the expected was "0"**. End Error DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started: 11:05:02 AM Finished:
>   11:12:25 AM Elapsed: 442.922 seconds. The package execution failed.
>   The step failed.

**Wednesday 4 PM:**

1. Opened the agent job
2. In job step, deselected SSIS catalog option (everything got reset)
3. Again selected SSIS catalog and provided the same server name
4. Selected the required package from catalog
5. Pressed OK

**Wednesday 7 PM:** Job ran successfully

**Thursday 7 PM:** Job failed with same above error.

**Friday 4 PM:**
I did the same thing what was done in Wednesday 4 PM.

**Friday 7 PM:**
Job ran successfully.

Why the package and SQL agent job scheduled is behaving like this?
Please provide your suggestions and help. I must fix this issue before the next run. Your kind help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are coming from 2005 to a higher version. Make sure the package runs in 32-bit mode using the /x86 flag or change the run directory for dtexec to the one in Program Files x86. The flag is in the command line exec, but there is a check box in the SQL Agent job if you are executing it as an SSIS package.

It will run fine locally because Visual Studio runs in 32-bit mode.

Comment: The package fails with the same error while I check run as "32 bit option" in SQL agent job.

Comment: I did not get your suggestion "change the run directory for dtexec to the one in Program Files x86. The flag is in the command line exe". Could you please elaborate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So when an SSIS package executes, it uses the dtexec.exe utility to run. So you should have a file path of something like **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe**. This one is the 64-bit one. The other one is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe**. Outside of this, I'm not sure why moving from 2005 up with a scheduled SSIS package of the same configuration would fail.

Comment: how to change the run directory for dtexec to the Program Files x86?

Comment: To force it to do so, change the job step from type SQL Server Integration Services Package to Operating system (CmdExec). Then add the full path of the command to the beginning of the Command. Somthing like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /SQL "\"Maintenance Plans\DatabaseIntegrityOptimization\"" /SERVER "\"Server\"" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "\"\Package\Subplan_1.Disable\"";false /REPORTING E

Comment: But why the job is running for a day and failing on next day?